# Converting Companion Object with Implicit

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to "add" a field to a companion object without changing the companion object itself, using an implicit. In the following example, I want to be able to access the property "name" from object A. Is this possible?

```
implicit def a2b(???): ??? = B

object A
class A

object B {
    val name = "Bob"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
implicit def a2b(aObj: A.type): B.type = B
```